# Ruby: convert day as decimal to day as name

Tags: ruby, date

Is it possible to convert quickly a strftime("%u") value to a strftime("%A") or do i need to build an equivalence hash like {"Monday" => 1, ......... "Sunday" => 6}

I have an Array with some day as decimal values

```
class_index=[2,6,7]
```

and I would like to loop through this array to build and array of days name like this

```
[nil, "Tuesday", nil, nil, nil, "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

so I could do

```
class_list=[]
class_index.each do |x|
  class_list[x-1] = convert x value to day name
end
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Monday 1, Sunday 6? You might want to recheck that ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
require "date"
DateTime.parse("Wednesday").wday # => 3
```

Oh, I now see you've expanded your question. How about:

```
[2,6,7].inject(Array.new(7)) { |memo,obj| memo[obj-1] = Date::DAYNAMES[obj%7]; memo }
```

Let me explain that one:

```
input = [2,6,7]
empty_array = Array.new(7) # => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
input.inject(empty_array) do |memo, obj| # loop through the input, and
                                         # use the empty array as a 'memo'
  day_name = Date::DAYNAMES[obj%7]       # get the day's name, modulo 7 (Sunday = 0)
  memo[obj-1] = day_name                 # save the day name in the empty array
  memo                                   # return the memo for the next iteration
end
```

The beauty of Ruby.

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed you could just pass a day name like that. +1

Comment: is there an equivalent to Date::DAYNAMES to get the .wday?

Comment: `Date::DAYNAMES.index("Saturday") # => 6`

Comment: And just in case you want Monday == 0 and Sunday == 6, you can do `Date::DAYNAMES[(i+1)%7]`

Answer (score 5):

To go from decimal to weekday:

```
require 'date'
Date::DAYNAMES[1]
# => "Monday"
```

So, in your example, you could simply do:

```
class_list=[]
class_index.each do |x|
  class_list[x-1] = Date::DAYNAMES[x-1]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one way that comes to mind:

```
require "date"

def weekday_index_to_name(index)
  date = Date.parse("2011-09-26") # Canonical Monday.
  (index - 1).times { date = date.succ }
  date.strftime("%A")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class_index=[2,6,7]

class_index.map{|day_num| Date::DAYNAMES[day_num%7]}

#=> ["Tuesday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

note that day names are from 0 to 6, so you can either work from 0 to 6 or have it modulo 7